# how can i see the tags values in codeigniter form with jquery tag-it?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, tag-it

I am using jQuery tagIt with Codeigniter.

But when I send the form to get the validation error I cant see the tags, despite I used to the input `set_value()`

Any idea?

Comment: Can you paste you code here ?

Comment: set_value('fieldname') only works when u have defined a validation rule for that field in your controller

Comment: check whether value is set in your input box

Comment: i checked the input is in display:none and the values is set seprate by comma like this: one,two,three

Answer (score 0):

You have to first assign a class name or Id name for the field. Then use that class name to enable TagIt on that field. here is an example.

```
<?php echo form_input('category', set_value('category',isset($categories) ? $categories : ''),'class="taxonomy"'); ?>
```

then use the class name in the tagit script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".taxonomy").tagit();
    allowSpaces: true
});
</script>
```